# Own Ajax Request to delete action in yii2 not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

In my Yii2 I am trying to write my own ajax request to perform delete action.

**My code for the action column button**
   **

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
    return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-prod" id="'.$model->product_id.'" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>';**                     
},
```

**My Ajax request for this :**

```
<?php
if($model!= null){
    foreach($model as $mod);
}
$this->registerJs('
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".delete-prod", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data:{"refID": id},
        url: "'.Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("product/delete?id=".$mod->product_id).'",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data.status){
                alert("hello");

            }else{
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
');
?>
```

**My Delete action in the controller**

```
public function actionDelete($id)       
{

    \app\models\Productlines::find()->where(['product_id' => $id])->one()->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

For some reason I just get the alert when i click the button. My delete action doesn't work. I get a **500 Internal Server Error**. Can any one help me out with this??

Thanks a million...

Comment: what error do you get in firebug?check the reason for internal server error

Comment: I get Internal Server Error: ** POST http://test.qsims.com/index.php/product/delete?id=4 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: where is your button that you click on it for delete?

Comment: the code for action column button.. I have given a class you can see there

Comment: change  type: "POST" to type:"GET" and try again

Comment: The problem is getting my id in the place of Url.. How do I pass the id which i have declared in the jquery to the URL?

Comment: I see a lot of errors in your code.I will give an answer by correcting the codes one by one.As I am not completely  aware of what you are trying to acheive.I need your cooperation and feedback on it

Comment: Yes sure @KiranMuralee

Comment: delete ?id=".$mod->product_id from your url and in your action get id by $_POST['refID'];

Comment: That does'nt get me the right product_id for some reason @yafater.. In action its fine but in url not working

Comment: you send your data by         data:{"refID": id}, and when you send your datas by post you don't need them as parameters for controller

Comment: @yafater I have given a detailed answer.Hope the OP understands it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Your delete button code

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
    return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-prod" 
data-id="'.json_encode(["prod_id" => $model->product_id,"area_id" => $model->area_id‌]).'" style="cursor:pointer;"></span>';                     
},
```

Your ajax request code

```
$url=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("product/delete");
$this->registerJs('
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".delete-prod", function() {

try{
    var model_obj = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-id"));   
    alert(model_obj.prod_id); //check whether you are getting the correct prod_id value 

    var prod_id = model_obj.prod_id;
    var area_id = model_obj.area_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data:{"prod_id":prod_id,"area_id":area_id},
        url: "'.$url.'",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ 
           alert(data.status);
        }
    });
   }
 catch(e)
 {
    alert(e); //check tosee any errors
 }

});
');
```

Your Controller code

```
public function actionDelete()       
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $p = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $prod_id=$p["prod_id"];
    $area_id=$p["area_id"];


    if(\app\models\Productlines::find()->where(['product_id' => $id])->one()->delete())
     {
         return [
            "status" => "success"
        ];
     }
     else
     {
          return [
            "status" => "failure"
        ];
     }


}
```

Comment: if I want to send more than 1 data to the controller how do i send it?

Comment: data:{"refID": id ,"anotherData":"testdata"}

Comment: I mean to say I want use my $model and send it... So like for example I have passed id = $model->product_id. The same way I want to pass $model->area_id to the controller

Comment: @Mohan Prasad my suggestion is that u change code like  return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-prod" data-id="{'prod_id':".$model->product_id.",'area_id':".$model->area_id."}"   style="cursor:pointer;"></span>';** .Then get this data-id attribute value in javascript as JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-id"));Learn more about JSON in http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

Comment: can you look at your new answer I have made edits It gets an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Mohan Prasad I will edit my answer :).I see you are having difficulty in understanding

Comment: I tried your edit.. The problem is I get undefined idnetifier 'prod_id' and undefined 'area_id'  @KiranMuralee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123524/discussion-between-kiran-muralee-and-mohan-prasad).